# Kivy Layout python

Tags: python, layout, kivy

I want to add buttons for Shop, Campaign, Arena, etc. The way I understand it, the layout is what allows the widgets to be moved. However, if I return game it seems to not use the layout, and if I return layout the background isn't there. What am I missing?

Here's my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import.   Window
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class Sprite(Image):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Sprite, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = self.texture_size

class Background(Widget):
    def __init__(self, source):
        super(Background, self).__init__()
        self.image = Sprite(source = source)
        self.add_widget(self.image)
        self.size = self.image.size

class Game(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Game, self).__init__()
        self.background = Background(source='Town.jpg')
        self.size = self.background.size
        self.add_widget(self.background)
        self.add_widget(a)


class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = FloatLayout()
        game = Game()
        Window.size = game.size 
        return game

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GameApp().run()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are creating a `FloatLayout` in your `build()` method, but you are not putting anything in the layout. So if you return `layout`, your app will be an empty layout.

Comment: Hey thanks. I believe I have it figured out. Now I am just curious. How do I make the buttons call functions from the kv file? Is that bind: func()?

Comment: In the `kv` file within a `Button:` rule, you can just add `on_release: some_func()`.

Comment: Ok! Thanks so much!